# StorageReference isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart

so i got this error in my code `Error: 'StorageReference' isn't a type.` i am trying to reference the here

```
    uploadBlog() async{
    if(selectedImage != null){

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      /// Uploading Image to firebase storage
      StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("BlogImages").child(
        "${randomAlphaNumeric(9)}.jpg"
      );
      final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage);

      var downloadUrl = await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
      print("this is url $downloadUrl");
    }else{

    }
  }
```

but get this error

```
Error: 'StorageReference' isn't a type.
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("BlogImages").child(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and this error

```
Error: 'StorageUploadTask' isn't a type.
  final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

pls i dont know what to do or how to fix it pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `firebase_storage >= 5.0.0-dev.1` the class `StorageReference` has been renamed to `Reference`.

You can check that and more breaking changes in [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage/CHANGELOG.md#500-dev1) file.

On your code just replace the type.

```
Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("BlogImages").child( "${randomAlphaNumeric(9)}.jpg");
```